# Creating a Fragment every time a getItem() fires?

Tags: android, sdk

In the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging), there is a `FragmentStatePageAdapter` that instantiates a `Fragment` every time `getItem` fires. Is this sane? I've checked, and this fires every time I swipe, which means it creates a `Fragment` every time? Is this correct?

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // Our object is just an integer :-P
    args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

I'm pretty new to Android, so I just wanted a sanity check on this. It doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

As per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html):

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to
>   the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the
>   saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much
>   less memory associated with each visited page as compared to
>   FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when
>   switching between pages.

Thus the FragmentStatePagerAdapter does all the heavy lifting to help you keep your memory footprint relatively low. To do this, it may destroy Fragments that are not visible.

In general, you can set the number of off-screen pages for a ViewPager to keep in memory with [`ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew that they might be destroyed, but every `Fragment` is a bit costly to generate (I draw the UI dynamically), so I'm wondering if I can save them in an `ArrayList` and just hand them out. Would that be a good solution, or would the `Fragment` be destroyed even so?

Comment: I'll only have 1-10 pages, so it sounds like I need a `FragmentPageAdapter`, huh...